# How would I tile windows in a SwiftUI Mac app?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, window

### The background:

I'm writing a cross-platform word game helper app in SwiftUI. It's useful for games like Wordle. (a game where you try to guess a 5 letter word by guessing other 5 letter words and using info about the matching letters to zero in on the solution.)

The app is also useful for other "multi-Wordle" games like Quordle, Octordle, and Sedecordle (4, 8, and 16 Wordle games at once.) For those multi-Wordle games, the Mac version of the app allows the user to open a separate Wordle window for each sub-game.

SwiftUI staggers each new window down and to the right of the previous window.

### The question:

How would I tile multiple windows so they neatly fill the screen in a row-major grid in SwiftUI? (Where each new window is placed to the right of the previous one until a row is filled, and then it creates a new row of windows directly below the previous one.)

I both want an option to tile windows as they are created, and a "tile windows" menu option for the Windows menu.

Comment: There is no native SwiftUI solution for this. You'll have to get the backing NSWindows and manage their positions yourself.

Comment: Shouldn't a LazyVGrid do the job or, I did not get something right?

Comment: I don't think you can use SwiftUI Grids on Windows. It wouldn't be a bad way to build a tiled Quordle/Octordle solver window, with the individual Wordle Solvers as Views inside the LazyVGrid.

Comment: @jnpdx, any suggestions on where to start to get at the backing UIWindows of all open app windows?

Comment: @DuncanC If you're on a Mac, they will be NSWindows -- I don't think you have any control over UIWindows on iOS. You could start with `NSApplication.shared.windows`. Or, if you want to get them from the SwiftUI side, use an NSViewRepresentable, and then query `view.window` to get the view that the representable is a part of.

Comment: I know very little about SwiftUI but I was just looking at the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bringing_multiple_windows_to_your_swiftui_app sample app. The `BookClubApp` file defines some windows. It shows how to give the window a default size and position. It's all pure SwiftUI code. I guess the trick would be how to calculate the next position of the next window but it's a start.

Comment: Looks like some info at [Positioning and sizing Windows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/positioning-and-sizing-windows).